# I am unable to install any packages on R

Tags: r

[this is the error which is showing whenever i am trying to download any new package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCrBO.jpg)

I have tried using CRANmirror() but still its not working

I am completely new to R

This is the entire error message in text format

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/abc/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘ggplot2’ is not available (for R version 4.0.2)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/4.0:
  cannot open URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/PACKAGES'
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
```

Comment: Please can you copy and paste the error message in text format rather than posting an image. thank you.

Comment: Try `options(repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")`. Also, where does `CRANmirror()` come from? When using a non-base function, please start your script with calls to `library()` in order for us to know where to find that function.

Comment: install.packages("ggplot2")
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/abc/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘ggplot2’ is not available (for R version 4.0.2)
Warning in install.

Comment: @user438383 i have commented the error message but this is not the full error message because we are allowed only certain number of characters in the comment section

Comment: @nitindalmia you can edit your post and include the full error message there, rather than in the comments. thank you.

Comment: If you use your browser (Firefox or whatever) to read https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES, does it work?

Comment: @user2554330 Yes, it works. I use Chrome and it works fine.

Comment: I'd guess that Windows (or some antivirus program on your system) is preventing R from accessing the Internet.